# Green's function for fractional Laplacian

Tags: reference-request, fractional-calculus, green-function

Consider the fractional differential equation 
\begin{align}
D_{|x|}^\alpha u(x) +bu(x)=f(x)
\end{align}
with $0<\alpha<2$ on an unbounded domain. Instead of $D_{|x|}^\alpha$ one also often sees $\Delta^{\alpha/2}$, meaning the fractional (symmetric) Laplacian with Fourier transform
\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}\left( D_{|x|}^\alpha u(x)\right) = |\kappa |^\alpha \tilde u(\kappa).
\end{align}
To compute the Green's function $G(x)$ of the above problem, I need the inverse Fourier transform of $g(\kappa)$, given by
\begin{align}
g(\kappa) = \frac{1}{|\kappa|^\alpha +b}.
\end{align}
I know, that for
\begin{align}
h(\kappa) = \frac{1}{\kappa^\alpha +b}
\end{align}
the inverse Fourier transform is given by
\begin{align}
H(x) = x^{\alpha-1} E_{\alpha,\alpha}(-bx^\alpha)
\end{align}
where $E_{\alpha,\beta}(x)$ is the Mittag-Leffler function.
Are there any references regarding this topic? I have also found numerous results for the Green's function on a domain that is a ball of size $R$ with $u(x)=u(|x|)$, meaning that we have a radial problem. However, this is not the case in my problem.

Any hint is very much appreciated.

Comment: I have a question about one of your statement. You said that for the function $g(\kappa)=\frac{1}{\kappa^\alpha +b}$,
the inverse Fourier transform is given by
$$
H(x) = x^{\alpha-1} E_{\alpha,\alpha}(-bx^\alpha)
$$
where $E_{\alpha,\beta}(x)$ is the Mittag-Leffler function. As far as I know, it should be the inverse Laplace transform.

Comment: Yes I think I made a mistake there, I will edit my question. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the H-function? Recently I studied this special function. I found it is very interesting because its Fourier transform is the Mittag-Lffler function.

Comment: Yes I have read about the H-function. I have read the papers by Mainardi et al., where they consider the fundamental solution of $D_t^\beta u = D_x^\alpha u$ and tried to interpret my problem as the limit $\beta \rightarrow 0$, however, that did not really work out.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "computing" the Green's function, and not sure if two years later you are still interested, but the inverse Fourier transform $G(x)$ of $g(\kappa)$ is the resolvent (a.k.a. $b$-potential) kernel for the fractional Laplacian. Although there is no closed-form expression, you can get a lot of information about $G$; for example: $G(x) \approx \min(|x|^{-n-\alpha},|x|^{-n+\alpha})$ (where $n$ is the dimension).